# Is an unprivileged LXC where the host user itself is mapped to 0 less secure of one where one of its subids is mapped to 0, and why?

Tags: security, non-root-user, lxc, namespace

Instead of creating "common" LXC unprivileged containers where all the users are mapped to (unprivileged) subuid/gid of my host user, I'm considering a mapping where my host user itself will be mapped to user 0 (root). They'd be very slim single-app containers.

The reason is that in this way I don't need the rootfs directory subtree, which resides in my user's home, to be namespace-chmod to a different user and I can delete it with a plain rm instead of a namespace one.

Is this kind of LXC less secure than the "common" one, and why is it? What could happen?